# Deploy from Jenkins to Archiva steps

Tags: jenkins, archiva

I see this question as a potential answer to my problem: [Deploy Artifact From Jenkins to Archiva with NAnt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15010016/deploy-artifact-from-jenkins-to-archiva-with-nant) however the chosen answer starts with: create a Jenkins task. How do I do that? I'm new to Jenkins and need to deploy from Jenkins to archiva.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a maven build there is a "post build action called "Deploy Artifacts to maven repository".
In the advanced section, configure the repository url.

And the repository Id (to ease your job you can use this plugin https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Config+File+Provider+Plugin)

As repository id is read from a maven settings file.

HTH

Comment: Cool this is helpful. What about artifact deployer plug in in Jenkins? Can I not just use that?

Comment: Also, I get red text telling me my directory that I want to get the artifacts from does not exist. Is there a format to follow?