# Calling Ant from Nant without batch

Tags: ant, nant

We have an automated build process that uses Nant scripts, and we just inherited a Java project that has an existing, working Ant script.  I have searched all over and it seems most people use a batch file to call Ant scripts from Nant.  This seems a little hacky to me.  Is there a way to call Ant scripts directly from Nant in task format?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5192832/how-to-run-a-nant-task-with-ant/5192899#5192899) similar question addresses it with a batch file but I want to do it without.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!-- calling the Ant build Process-->
    <target name="AntBuildProcess" description="Created to call the Ant build during this NAnt build process" >
        <echo message="Starting the Ant Build Process..." />
        <exec program="ant" commandline='-buildfile YourAntBuild.xml' failonerror="true"/>
    </target>
```

Then during your Build process, you just call this target at the point you need it to be built. `<call target="AntBuildProcess" />`

Comment: Calling Ant directly, passing the buildfile, works nicely.  Other people had suggested creating a separate batch file and call that batch file, which seemed messy.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Ant ***is*** a batch file. Take a look, and you'll see a file called `ant.bat` in the `%ANT_HOME%\bin` directory.

Ant is actually a Java program, so you could [launch it from the java command](http://ant.apache.org/manual/running.html#viajava) by running the class `org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher` which is basically what the `ant.bat` file is doing.

However, why reinvent the wheel? The `ant.bat` runs the Java command the right way, gives you options to change the way it's executed, and makes sure everything is setup correctly.

---

## Addendum

I see, Nant, unlike Ant, will always call `cmd.exe` and use suffixes and `%PATHEXEC%` to figure out if something is a batch script or other type of script. Thus, if you want to run Ant using Ant as a batch script via `<exec/>` you would do this:

```
<exec executable="cmd.exe"
    dir="${working.dir}">
    <arg value="/c"/>
    <arg value="ant.bat"/>
</exec>
```

However, in Nant you can simply do it this way:

```
<exec program="ant"
    workingdir=${working.dir}"/>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  The batch file I was talking about is what most people *create* to get around directly calling Ant in some way.  I was wondering if there was a task just for calling Ant scripts from Nant.

Comment: Actually, looking at Nant, I see that Nant will treat batch scripts as if they were executables. Nant always spawns a `cmd.exe`. In Unix, the `exec` command will look to see if the _command_ starts with a `x03533` or `#!`. If it does, it'll consider that a _shebang_ and spawn the process specified. This doesn't work on Win32 which is why you need to call `ant` with the `cmd.exe`. Nant doesn't have this issue, so saying your executable is `ant` should work.